# access specific element of list in Boost PropertyTree (JSON)

Tags: c++, json, list, boost, element

I have data like this

```
{"json": "a_string", "data": [0,1,2,3,4]}
```

I’m trying to access any specific element of "data" "directly".

Inspired by the approach of iterating over the elements, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31345401/parse-json-array-as-stdstring-with-boost-ptree%22here%22), I used the iterator to get the first element.

```
root.get_child("data").begin()->second.get_value<int>();
```

But I am quite sure there should be an option to just say something like .get(0) or .get(1), but this call needs the knowledge I am operating on something like a list / vector.

Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include<boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::property_tree;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    string str("{\"json\": \"a_string\", \"data\": [0,1,2,3,4]}");
    stringstream ss(str);
    ptree root;
    read_json(ss,root);

    int first_value = root.get_child("data").begin()->second.get_value<int>();

    cout << first_value << endl;
    getc(stdin);
}
```

Comment: I linked to the question you are referring to in my question. It does not answer my question though. I want to access the elements directly, not iterate over them.

Comment: Is it a random access iterator? If yes, just add the offset. If not, copy it into your own container and use that.

Comment: Okay, your proposal helped me out a bit. If I save the iterator with "auto it = root.get_child("data").begin();", then "std::advance(it,3);", I get the desired value when using it. But the question how to access the value "directly" remains. Isn't there an easy way?